# Getting city and country information on Android

Tags: android, location

I want to get a users city and country information WITHOUT GPS enabled? Is there a way to obtain this data from their carriers?

Comment: by carrier i don't mean using a paid service, but information about the connected radio tower?

Comment: We can get the longitude and latitude values from cell towers. But I dont know whether we can know the name of the location without connecting to GPS or not.

Comment: @Krishna : if we have latitude and longitude values, we can get location name using reverse geocoding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LocationManager to get the location. You need to add permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in the manifest file

Answer (score 1):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCode = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```